# TypeError: date.getTime is not a function

Tags: javascript

I own a little game and my coder is not available. After an update he did, I have this error "date.getTime is not a function" in the console that causes crashes and I'm alone and very novice. I'd like you guys to please help me understand on how to solve it. Thanks

```
  hasPlayedInTheWeek(date) {
    var lastMonday = new Date();
    lastMonday.setDate(lastMonday.getDate() - (lastMonday.getDay()-1));
    lastMonday.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    const res = lastMonday.getTime() < date.getTime() && date.getTime() < ( lastMonday.getTime() + 604800000);
    return res;
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `date` as an arg to your function `hasPlayedInTheWeek`

Comment: How are you calling the function? Are you sure you are passing a `Date` object as the first argument?

Comment: For starters, you are missing `function` keyword that should go just before `hasPlayedInTheWeek(date)`

Comment: That being said, It'd be nice if you can post your .js file code. I'm sure you'll receive better help

Comment: Just check if date is instance of Date if not then maybe return false: `if(!(date instanceof Date)){return false;}` first line of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I can't find it declared anywhere, he probably forgot and isn't replying right now. Is there a way for me to declare it ?

Comment: @Dustin That function gets passed a parameter date which may or may not be instance of Date. You can search the file for "hasPlayedInTheWeek(" and see where it's called and with what parameters. But to get rid of the error you can just put the instanceof check I mention in previous comment to your function.

Comment: Thank you user3647971 and all for replying. @mishsx My js file is 700 lines long. Will it be a problem if I paste here ?

Comment: @user3647971 I added if(!(date instanceof Date)){return false;} and it stopped working. Does this mean that date is an instance of Date ?

Comment: Try logging `Object.prototype.toString.call(date)`.

Comment: @ Dustin No It wont be a problem.

Comment: @mishsx Thank you, following your advise I edited the post and posted a pastebin link to the whole Js file. Could you guys please have a look ?

Comment: Okay so right off the bat I see an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` Investigating more on the issue

Comment: Did you check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

add this before `const res`:

```
date = new Date(date);
```

code:

```
hasPlayedInTheWeek(date) {
    var lastMonday = new Date();
    lastMonday.setDate(lastMonday.getDate() - (lastMonday.getDay()-1));
    lastMonday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    date = new Date(date)
    const res = lastMonday.getTime() < date.getTime() && date.getTime() < ( lastMonday.getTime() + 604800000);
    return res;
  }
```